# Inner Broadcast receiver does not work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, inner-classes

I create an inner receiver InnerReceiver

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity{
  ...

       class InnerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Log.v("InnerReceiver", "onReceive");
          }
       }

 ...
 }
```

The receiver is called as following:

```
   AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context,MainActivity.InnerReceiver.class), 0);

   mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000,
                10000,
                pi);
```

The inner class is declared as:

However, the inner receiver is never called! Is anything wrong ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register it in the [`<receiver>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceiver) tag in your AndroidManifest.xml or dynamically by calling [`registerReceiver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29).

It may need to be declared `public`, rather than `package-private` as you have it. See more about Java access control [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

You will also need to broadcast something for it to receive, such as by calling [`sendBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29).